# is it possible to reset ios app (Ready for sale) version from v2.xx to v1.0 again?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm wondering if apple will allow me to reset my app version to 1.0 again because my app is still in beta and i would relaunch it again

thank you.

Comment: No, version numbers must always increase

Comment: Who cares if it's in beta...put v90000 if you want. It's just a number, upload any version you want and just put a number on it.

Comment: answer is no - https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Managing%20Published%20Apps#11310557) . You cannot. Need to add a new build ( if error build is in production you can ask to expedited  process )

Comment: @AmodGokhale thank u

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no!

You cannot because version numbers must always increase. if you need to add a new build ( if error build is in production you can ask to expedited process )

visit this [link](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Managing%20Published%20Apps#11310557) to learn more.